# How can I scroll page up/down in more/less in iterm2?

Tags: iterm2

I have a question with iterm2 when using MacOS.

I have tried to reset the short keys `page up/down` to `fn+↑/↓` and it worked nicely in zsh, but I can't use `fn+↑/↓` to scroll `page up/down` by using the command more/less to check some files.  Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Use Shift + page up works well